# RTL8812AE WiFi card driver install fails

Tags: drivers, software-installation, realtek-wireless

Trying to install some drivers for my RTL8812AE WiFi card.

I was able to install Sophos by downloading it, dragging the .sh file into terminal and it did it through there.

Can't get it to work for my WiFi card installer, though.

```
some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:286: /home/***/Documents/RTL8812AE_Linux_v4.3.2_12208.20140904/driver/rtl8812AE_linux_v4.3.2_12208.20140903/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1606: _module_/home/***/Documents/RTL8812AE_Linux_v4.3.2_12208.20140904/driver/rtl8812AE_linux_v4.3.2_12208.20140903] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.0.0-29-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:1323: modules] Error 2
##################################################
Compile make driver error: 2
Please check error Mesg
```

Comment: You may need to grant the execution permission. 

Run `chmod u+x installer.sh` within the same directory as the installer, `installer.sh` being the filename of your installer. You should then be able to run the file by issuing the command `./installer.sh` within the same directory. 

The explanation is that the file may not be marked as executable, and that is what the above command does. `chmod` is a command used to set permissions on files and directories. `u` means set the permissions for the current user only and `x` means granting execution permission.

Comment: I get this <pre>Authentication requested [root] for make clean:
Password: 
su: Authentication failure
Authentication requested [root] for make driver:
Password: 
su: Authentication failure
##################################################
Compile make driver error: 1
Please check error Mesg
</pre>

Comment: It sounds like the installer needs root permissions. You can either run `sudo su -` to get to a root prompt and then run the installer by issuing the command `./installer.sh`, or you can just run `sudo ./installer.sh`. In both cases you'll be asked to enter a password, this is your own login password.

If that doesn't work, your user may not be allowed to use the sudo command, but that's a separate issue.

Comment: <pre>some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:286: /home/****/Documents/RTL8812AE_Linux_v4.3.2_12208.20140904/driver/rtl8812AE_linux_v4.3.2_12208.20140903/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1606: _module_/home/****/Documents/RTL8812AE_Linux_v4.3.2_12208.20140904/driver/rtl8812AE_linux_v4.3.2_12208.20140903] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory &apos;/usr/src/linux-headers-5.0.0-29-generic&apos;
make: *** [Makefile:1323: modules] Error 2
###############################################
Compile make driver error: 2
Please check error Mesg
</pre>

Comment: @venomx As you see, there's no formatting in Comments. Would you please click [edit] and add that information from the two comments above into the question, where there is formatting, then delete the comments by clicking on _delete_ at the end of each? Please do not click Add Comment, please use [edit] instead. Formatting tips are at https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code

Comment: @venomx  And, when you post the results of running an install, please include the command you typed, and the script file contents so we can see what commands you got from Realtek which failed.

Comment: Your wireless driver is from 2014. You need to try a newer driver. See https://github.com and use the search bar.

Comment: On github they have RTL8812AU but not RTL8812AE

Comment: @venomx show me `dkms status` and `sudo lshw -C network`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll surely miss them.