# Realtek RTL8812AE has slower connection in Ubuntu than in Windows

Tags: realtek-wireless

Fitted an [Addon AWP1200E 5Ghz WiFi card](http://www.addon-tech.com/new_/product/html/?136.html) today which depends on Linux drivers from files in **/drivers/linux/AWP1200E_linux.zip/RTL8812AE_Linux_v4.3.2_12208.20140904/** extracted from http://www.addon-tech.com/new_/down/upload/20150812/1439396363.zip .

On my 74mb connection I only get about 37 mb/sec; hardwired I get about 67 mb/sec and on my Windows PC I used to get over 70mb/sec with WiFi.

Why is it slower on Ubuntu? How can I get this card to deliver the speed I got with Windows? Here's what `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3 && rfkill list` shows:

```
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8812AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8812] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8812AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8812]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8821ae
    Kernel modules: rtl8821ae
06:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: How do i enable full duplex ? I did some reading and think this is my problem

Comment: @venomx Did you run the command `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3 && rfkill list` if so, edit your question and paste the output of the command into your question.

Comment: Yes dude ive just done that

Comment: Your wireless driver is from 2014. You need to try a newer driver. See https://github.com and use the search bar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RTL8812AE WiFi card driver install fails](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1176918/rtl8812ae-wifi-card-driver-install-fails)

Comment: Edit your question and show me `dkms status` and `sudo lshw -C network`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll surely miss them.

Comment: Not seeing full duplex settings when I read the contents of the directory /drivers/linux/AWP1200E_linux.zip/RTL8812AE_Linux_v4.3.2_12208.20140904/documents so may I please ask you to run sudo apt-get install ethtool net-tools && cat /proc/net/dev | awk '{print $1}' && ip addr then add that and the result into the question with 'edit' please?

Comment: status please...

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same issue for days (had 6 Mb/s on my Ubuntu 18.04)
Downloaded that driver from github and now I finally have my network running at 144Mb/s:

https://github.com/mid-kid/r8822be

I'm a total noob so if any other noob out there has this issue that I had, and specifically those that want to kill themselves after buying Lenovo Legion Y530 and thought it will be a walk in a park installing Ubuntu 18.04...

1. Download as a zip the whole git from the link above
2. Rename the old driver file (it's possible that the kernel version had changed by the time you're reading this):

In one terminal (let's call this one term1):

cd /lib/modules/5.0.0-29-generic/kernel/drivers/staging/rtlwifi

sudo mv r8822be.ko r8822be_.ko

ll

(you should see that the file name had been changed successfully)

3. Extract the zip somewhere (I have a folder that contains some other  drivers that I tried, including some of the TP-LINK dongles I bought, none really worked of course...)
4. In another terminal (to be called term2), go to the unzipped folder (where the readme file is) and follow the readme file instructions. For me, I did it like so:

./make

sudo ./make install

5. Now back to term1, ll again to check if it wrote the file. Hopefully it did.
6. Reboot.

Hope it works for you!

If it did, I think you can remove the r8822be_.ko now (I made a copy just in case)

If anyone has comments I would love to read them

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to this post https://askubuntu.com/a/1399638 I fixed the problem. Just had to run one command that overrides wifi settings.

Beware though, it might disable Bluetooth. Remove the `bt_coex_active=N` to test if you can still have Bluetooth.

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=N power_save=0 power_level=5"
```

What it does is creates a new file in `/etc/modprobe.d/` directory called `iwlwifi-opt.conf` and sets some WiFi settings by adding text to that file.