# Wifi / Ethernet disconnecting at random times on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, wireless, ethernet

My connection via Wifi or USB Ethernet (from an Iphone) stops after some random time (2min to hours). It has been like this for two weeks now. Bluetooth is disabled.

The same happens in Windows, where I already tried to install the drivers from MSI (motherboard manufacturer) and reset the wifi to default parameters.

Nothing much more to say since I have no idea why it does this.
Turning the wifi off and back on fixes the issue temporarily.

### OS

- `lsb_release -a`: 
  No LSB modules are available. 
  Distributor ID: Ubuntu 
  Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS 
  Release:    22.04 
  Codename:   jammy
- `uname -r`:
  Originally: 6.2.0-37-generic
  Now: 6.5.0-1009-oem

### Command Outputs / Logs

- Step 2 from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WirelessTroubleshootingProcedure : 
  https://pastebin.com/igaFvi6n
- `sudo journalctl -fu NetworkManager`: https://pastebin.com/eAT89jSx in these logs, the first line seems to correspond to the time I lose connection. The following lines correspond to the time I turn off and on the wifi.

### What I have tried

- Disabling sleep mode from https://askubuntu.com/a/1399353
- `sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=N power_save=0 power_level=5"` from https://askubuntu.com/a/1399638
- `echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-fix.conf > /dev/null` from https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/702422
- `sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*` from https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2456744
- Switching to Ubuntu 23, had issues with my Nvidia GPU..
- Completely reinstalled Ubuntu from a bootable USB
- Updated to kernel 6.5.0-1009-oem

Please tell me if you need more info, I will edit the post.

Thanks for your help