# WiFi Stops after several minutes

Tags: wireless, 22.04

## Pastebin Information

- [working](https://pastebin.com/GLXT7J9s)
- [broken](https://pastebin.com/5tZkHdny)
- [Full dmesg pastebin from failure](https://pastebin.com/4uUNAnsm)
- [also a post I made on the ubuntu forum](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2496475)

## Original Question

I purchased a new NVME SSD and installed Ubuntu on that drive.

When Ubuntu first starts, I'm connected to the internet and then after some time (between 10-30 minutes) wifi stops working. It seems [similar to this issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1397239/wi-fi-connection-keeps-disconnecting). This machine runs windows on another SSD and does not have the same issues with wifi, so it's definitely some setting in Ubuntu. I've also updated the BIOS of my motherboard to the latest version.

When I start, the network is enabled

```
kyle@Strawberry:~$ sudo lshw -class network
[sudo] password for kyle: 
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX210/AX211/AX411 160MHz
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: wlp9s0
       version: 1a
       serial: bc:09:1b:0f:26:7a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=6.5.0-26-generic firmware=83.e8f84e98.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-83.uc ip=192.168.1.16 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:24 memory:fc600000-fc603fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Controller I225-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0a:00.0
       logical name: enp10s0
       version: 03
       serial: a0:36:bc:ac:ab:fd
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igc driverversion=6.5.0-26-generic firmware=1082:8770 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:34 memory:fc200000-fc2fffff memory:fc300000-fc303fff
```

but after some time, the wifi interface shows up as disabled. `ifconfig` also shows a network that is up

```
kyle@Strawberry:~$ ifconfig
enp10s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether a0:36:bc:ac:ab:fd  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xfc200000-fc2fffff  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 812  bytes 84490 (84.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 812  bytes 84490 (84.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp9s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.16  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::58f8:a2b8:2c2d:9b00  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether bc:09:1b:0f:26:7a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 10218  bytes 9739314 (9.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6650  bytes 1418314 (1.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

when the wifi goes down, `wlp9s0` disappears and `sudo ifconfig wlp9s0 up` fails to bring the network up (`SIOCSIFFLAGS: Connection timed out`).

## What I've tried

- disable windows hybrid shutdown
- set `wifi.powersave = 2`
- disable wpa_supplicant (didn't work, wpa_supplicant is now enabled again)
- Update the BIOS

**Other information**

```
kyle@Strawberry:~$ sudo iwlist freq
lo        no frequency information.

enp10s0   no frequency information.

wlp9s0    32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz
          Current Frequency:5.18 GHz (Channel 36)
```

```
kyle@Strawberry:~$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp10s0   no wireless extensions.

wlp9s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Kyle's Wi-Fi Network"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.18 GHz  Access Point: 6C:CD:D6:4B:EF:F3   
          Bit Rate=720.6 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=53/70  Signal level=-57 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:152   Missed beacon:0
```

## Edits

Seems like the modem manager dies?

```
journalctl -u NetworkManager

Mar 28 16:50:58 Strawberry systemd[1]: Started Network Manager.
Mar 28 16:50:58 Strawberry NetworkManager[13672]: <info>  [1711662658.5808] bus-manager: acquired D-Bus service "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
Mar 28 16:50:58 Strawberry NetworkManager[13672]: <info>  [1711662658.5826] manager[0x63585a77f020]: monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
Mar 28 16:50:58 Strawberry NetworkManager[13672]: <info>  [1711662658.5826] monitoring ifupdown state file '/run/network/ifstate'.
Mar 28 16:50:58 Strawberry NetworkManager[13672]: <info>  [1711662658.6351] hostname: hostname: using hostnamed
Mar 28 16:50:58 Strawberry NetworkManager[13672]: <info>  [1711662658.6352] hostname: static hostname changed from (none) to "Strawberry"
Mar 28 16:50:58 Strawberry NetworkManager[13672]: <info>  [1711662658.6353] dns-mgr[0x63585a7582a0]: init: dns=systemd-resolved rc-manager=unmanaged (auto), plugin=systemd-resolved
Mar 28 16:50:58 Strawberry NetworkManager[13672]: <info>  [1711662658.6358] rfkill1: found Wi-Fi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:03:00.0/0000:04:08.0/0000:06:00.0/0000:07:04.0/000>
Mar 28 16:50:58 Strawberry NetworkManager[13672]: <info>  [1711662658.6360] manager[0x63585a77f020]: rfkill: Wi-Fi hardware radio set enabled
Mar 28 16:50:58 Strawberry NetworkManager[13672]: <info>  [1711662658.6360] manager[0x63585a77f020]: rfkill: WWAN hardware radio set enabled
Mar 28 16:50:58 Strawberry NetworkManager[13672]: <info>  [1711662658.6366] Loaded device plugin: NMWwanFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-wwan.so)
Mar 28 16:50:58 Strawberry NetworkManager[13672]: <info>  [1711662658.6367] Loaded device plugin: NMAtmManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-adsl.so)
Mar 28 16:50:58 Strawberry NetworkManager[13672]: <info>  [1711662658.6369] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-bluetooth.so)
Mar 28 16:50:58 Strawberry NetworkManager[13672]: <info>  [1711662658.6372] Loaded device plugin: NMTeamFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-team.so)
Mar 28 16:50:58 Strawberry NetworkManager[13672]: <info>  [1711662658.6373] Loaded device plugin: NMWifiFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-wifi.so)
Mar 28 16:50:58 Strawberry NetworkManager[13672]: <info>  [1711662658.6374] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Mar 28 16:50:58 Strawberry NetworkManager[13672]: <info>  [1711662658.6375] manager: rfkill: WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Mar 28 16:50:58 Strawberry NetworkManager[13672]: <info>  [1711662658.6375] manager: Networking is enabled by state file
Mar 28 16:50:58 Strawberry NetworkManager[13672]: <info>  [1711662658.6376] settings: Loaded settings plugin: ifupdown ("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-settings-plugin-ifupdown.so")
Mar 28 16:50:58 Strawberry NetworkManager[13672]: <info>  [1711662658.6376] settings: Loaded settings plugin: keyfile (internal)
Mar 28 16:50:58 Strawberry NetworkManager[13672]: <info>  [1711662658.6376] ifupdown: management mode: unmanaged
Mar 28 16:50:58 Strawberry NetworkManager[13672]: <info>  [1711662658.6377] ifupdown: interfaces file /etc/network/interfaces doesn't exist
Mar 28 16:50:58 Strawberry NetworkManager[13672]: <info>  [1711662658.6384] dhcp-init: Using DHCP client 'internal'
Mar 28 16:50:58 Strawberry NetworkManager[13672]: <info>  [1711662658.6385] device (lo): carrier: link connected
Mar 28 16:50:58 Strawberry NetworkManager[13672]: <info>  [1711662658.6385] manager: (lo): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1)
Mar 28 16:50:58 Strawberry NetworkManager[13672]: <info>  [1711662658.6395] manager: (enp10s0): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
Mar 28 16:50:58 Strawberry NetworkManager[13672]: <info>  [1711662658.6396] device (enp10s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Mar 28 16:50:58 Strawberry NetworkManager[13672]: <info>  [1711662658.6402] device (wlp9s0): driver supports Access Point (AP) mode
Mar 28 16:50:58 Strawberry NetworkManager[13672]: <info>  [1711662658.6405] manager: (wlp9s0): new 802.11 Wi-Fi device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3)
Mar 28 16:50:58 Strawberry NetworkManager[13672]: <info>  [1711662658.6406] device (wlp9s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Mar 28 16:51:09 Strawberry NetworkManager[13672]: <warn>  [1711662669.6752] platform-linux: do-change-link[3]: failure changing link: failure 110 (Connection timed out)
Mar 28 16:51:09 Strawberry NetworkManager[13672]: <info>  [1711662669.6757] failed to open /run/network/ifstate
Mar 28 16:51:09 Strawberry NetworkManager[13672]: <info>  [1711662669.6785] modem-manager: ModemManager available
Mar 28 16:51:09 Strawberry NetworkManager[13672]: <info>  [1711662669.6800] agent-manager: agent[84247716e3534200,:1.87/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1000]: agent registered
Mar 28 16:51:14 Strawberry NetworkManager[13672]: <error> [1711662674.6793] device (wlp9s0): Couldn't initialize supplicant interface: Timeout was reached
```

```
journalctl -u ModemManager
-- Boot c42b6d6b81e04ae49f9efd1dc079ff1a --
Mar 28 14:13:56 Strawberry systemd[1]: Starting Modem Manager...
Mar 28 14:13:56 Strawberry ModemManager[902]: <info>  ModemManager (version 1.20.0) starting in system bus...
Mar 28 14:13:56 Strawberry systemd[1]: Started Modem Manager.
Mar 28 14:13:59 Strawberry ModemManager[902]: <info>  [base-manager] couldn't check support for device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:03:00.0/0000:04:08.0/0000:06:00.0/0000:07:04.0/0000:09:00.0': no>
Mar 28 14:13:59 Strawberry ModemManager[902]: <info>  [base-manager] couldn't check support for device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:03:00.0/0000:04:08.0/0000:06:00.0/0000:07:05.0/0000:0a:00.0': no>
Mar 28 14:25:11 Strawberry ModemManager[902]: <info>  [base-manager] couldn't check support for device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:03:00.0/0000:04:08.0/0000:06:00.0/0000:07:05.0/0000:0a:00.0': no>
Mar 28 14:25:11 Strawberry ModemManager[902]: <info>  [base-manager] couldn't check support for device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:03:00.0/0000:04:08.0/0000:06:00.0/0000:07:04.0/0000:09:00.0': no>
Mar 28 16:52:27 Strawberry ModemManager[902]: <info>  caught signal, shutting down...
Mar 28 16:52:27 Strawberry systemd[1]: Stopping Modem Manager...
Mar 28 16:52:27 Strawberry ModemManager[902]: <info>  ModemManager is shut down
Mar 28 16:52:27 Strawberry systemd[1]: ModemManager.service: Deactivated successfully.
Mar 28 16:52:27 Strawberry systemd[1]: Stopped Modem Manager.
```

all of that seems to occur when some statistics command fails to be sent

```
[   45.341856] audit: type=1107 audit(1711670866.055:78): pid=850 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.3" pid=2419 label="snap.snap-store.snap-store" peer_pid=861 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[   45.341995] audit: type=1107 audit(1711670866.055:79): pid=850 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Authority" member="CheckAuthorization" mask="send" name=":1.3" pid=2419 label="snap.snap-store.snap-store" peer_pid=861 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[   45.342955] audit: type=1107 audit(1711670866.055:80): pid=850 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.3" pid=2419 label="snap.snap-store.snap-store" peer_pid=861 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[   45.343076] audit: type=1107 audit(1711670866.055:81): pid=850 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Authority" member="CheckAuthorization" mask="send" name=":1.3" pid=2419 label="snap.snap-store.snap-store" peer_pid=861 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[   45.524438] audit: type=1400 audit(1711670866.239:82): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.snap-store.snap-store" name="/etc/appstream.conf" pid=2419 comm="snap-store" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[   45.589885] audit: type=1400 audit(1711670866.303:83): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" class="cap" profile="/snap/snapd/21184/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=2788 comm="snap-confine" capability=12  capname="net_admin"
[   46.134926] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   46.134986] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   46.135014] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   46.135037] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   46.168806] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   46.168846] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   46.168874] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   46.168898] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   46.200284] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   46.200334] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   46.200361] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   46.200385] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   51.988573] pcieport 0000:00:02.1: AER: Uncorrected (Fatal) error received: 0000:07:04.0
[   59.028509] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: time out after 2000ms.
[   59.028518] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Current CMD queue read_ptr 156 write_ptr 157
[   59.046435] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[   59.046436] Timeout waiting for hardware access (CSR_GP_CNTRL 0xffffffff)
[   59.046456] WARNING: CPU: 7 PID: 851 at drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/pcie/trans.c:2194 __iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access+0x192/0x1a0 [iwlwifi]
[   59.046473] Modules linked in: rfcomm ccm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg nvidia_uvm(PO) bnep intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common nvidia_drm(PO) nvidia_modeset(PO) edac_mce_amd binfmt_misc iwlmvm snd_hda_codec_hdmi kvm_amd snd_hda_intel nvidia(PO) snd_intel_dspcfg nls_iso8859_1 snd_intel_sdw_acpi mac80211 kvm snd_usb_audio snd_hda_codec snd_usbmidi_lib snd_hda_core snd_ump libarc4 snd_hwdep irqbypass btusb snd_seq_midi crct10dif_pclmul snd_seq_midi_event polyval_clmulni btrtl polyval_generic btbcm ghash_clmulni_intel snd_rawmidi sha256_ssse3 btintel sha1_ssse3 btmtk mc aesni_intel snd_seq crypto_simd snd_pcm iwlwifi bluetooth cryptd snd_seq_device rapl joydev asus_nb_wmi input_leds eeepc_wmi wmi_bmof ecdh_generic k10temp snd_timer ccp ecc cfg80211 snd drm_kms_helper soundcore mac_hid sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport drm efi_pstore ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic usbhid hid mfd_aaeon asus_wmi ucsi_ccg ledtrig_audio sparse_keymap typec_ucsi typec platform_profile crc32_pclmul nvme ahci i2c_piix4
[   59.046539]  libahci igc nvme_core xhci_pci i2c_nvidia_gpu nvme_common i2c_ccgx_ucsi xhci_pci_renesas video wmi gpio_amdpt
[   59.046548] CPU: 7 PID: 851 Comm: NetworkManager Tainted: P           O       6.5.0-26-generic #26~22.04.1-Ubuntu
[   59.046550] Hardware name: ASUS System Product Name/ROG STRIX X670E-E GAMING WIFI, BIOS 0514 09/07/2022
[   59.046551] RIP: 0010:__iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access+0x192/0x1a0 [iwlwifi]
[   59.046561] Code: 89 df e8 61 5c fe ff 4c 89 ef e8 09 ab f7 da e9 57 ff ff ff 44 89 e6 48 c7 c7 e0 8a c2 c0 c6 05 db ed 02 00 01 e8 de 99 f3 d9 <0f> 0b eb 95 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90
[   59.046563] RSP: 0018:ffffad2b422d3368 EFLAGS: 00010246
[   59.046564] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff975e9b5c0028 RCX: 0000000000000000
[   59.046565] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 0000000000000000
[   59.046566] RBP: ffffad2b422d3398 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
[   59.046567] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: 00000000ffffffff
[   59.046568] R13: ffff975e9b5c35cc R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000000
[   59.046569] FS:  0000770a724514c0(0000) GS:ffff97659dbc0000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[   59.046571] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[   59.046572] CR2: 000077ed26497ae0 CR3: 00000001121fe000 CR4: 0000000000750ee0
[   59.046573] PKRU: 55555554
[   59.046574] Call Trace:
[   59.046575]  <TASK>
[   59.046578]  ? show_regs+0x6d/0x80
[   59.046582]  ? __warn+0x89/0x160
[   59.046585]  ? __iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access+0x192/0x1a0 [iwlwifi]
[   59.046596]  ? report_bug+0x17e/0x1b0
[   59.046600]  ? handle_bug+0x46/0x90
[   59.046602]  ? exc_invalid_op+0x18/0x80
[   59.046604]  ? asm_exc_invalid_op+0x1b/0x20
[   59.046608]  ? __iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access+0x192/0x1a0 [iwlwifi]
[   59.046617]  ? __iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access+0x192/0x1a0 [iwlwifi]
[   59.046627]  iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access+0x1a/0x50 [iwlwifi]
[   59.046636]  iwl_force_nmi+0xe3/0x100 [iwlwifi]
[   59.046645]  iwl_trans_sync_nmi_with_addr+0x14e/0x170 [iwlwifi]
[   59.046656]  iwl_trans_pcie_sync_nmi+0x47/0x80 [iwlwifi]
[   59.046666]  iwl_trans_txq_send_hcmd_sync+0x356/0x370 [iwlwifi]
[   59.046677]  ? __pfx_autoremove_wake_function+0x10/0x10
[   59.046681]  iwl_trans_txq_send_hcmd+0xb8/0x170 [iwlwifi]
[   59.046691]  iwl_trans_send_cmd+0x81/0x110 [iwlwifi]
[   59.046700]  iwl_mvm_send_cmd+0x38/0xa0 [iwlmvm]
[   59.046715]  iwl_mvm_request_statistics+0x12e/0x1b0 [iwlmvm]
[   59.046725]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0x7f
[   59.046728]  ? __pfx_iwl_wait_stats_complete+0x10/0x10 [iwlmvm]
[   59.046740]  iwl_mvm_mac_sta_statistics+0xeb/0x140 [iwlmvm]
[   59.046751]  drv_sta_statistics+0x90/0x1c0 [mac80211]
[   59.046780]  sta_set_sinfo+0x73/0xaa0 [mac80211]
[   59.046802]  ieee80211_dump_station+0x6f/0xa0 [mac80211]
[   59.046828]  nl80211_dump_station+0x14b/0x2c0 [cfg80211]
[   59.046856]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0x7f
[   59.046858]  ? __mod_lruvec_page_state+0x12f/0x160
[   59.046865]  netlink_dump+0x1c0/0x340
[   59.046870]  __netlink_dump_start+0x1ef/0x2a0
[   59.046873]  ? ep_done_scan+0xe4/0x100
[   59.046877]  genl_family_rcv_msg_dumpit+0x111/0x120
[   59.046879]  ? __pfx_genl_start+0x10/0x10
[   59.046881]  ? __pfx_nl80211_dump_station+0x10/0x10 [cfg80211]
[   59.046898]  ? __pfx_genl_parallel_done+0x10/0x10
[   59.046901]  genl_family_rcv_msg+0x116/0x250
[   59.046903]  ? __pfx_nl80211_dump_station+0x10/0x10 [cfg80211]
[   59.046921]  genl_rcv_msg+0x4c/0xb0
[   59.046923]  ? do_sys_poll+0x1ff/0x290
[   59.046926]  ? __pfx_genl_rcv_msg+0x10/0x10
[   59.046927]  netlink_rcv_skb+0x5a/0x110
[   59.046931]  genl_rcv+0x28/0x50
[   59.046932]  netlink_unicast+0x1b0/0x2a0
[   59.046935]  netlink_sendmsg+0x25e/0x4e0
[   59.046937]  ____sys_sendmsg+0x3ec/0x420
[   59.046940]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0x7f
[   59.046943]  ___sys_sendmsg+0x9a/0xf0
[   59.046947]  ? __pfx_pollwake+0x10/0x10
[   59.046950]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0x7f
[   59.046953]  __sys_sendmsg+0x89/0xf0
[   59.046957]  __x64_sys_sendmsg+0x1d/0x30
[   59.046958]  do_syscall_64+0x58/0x90
[   59.046961]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0x7f
[   59.046962]  ? do_syscall_64+0x67/0x90
[   59.046964]  ? do_syscall_64+0x67/0x90
[   59.046966]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0x7f
[   59.046968]  ? do_syscall_64+0x67/0x90
[   59.046969]  ? sysvec_apic_timer_interrupt+0x4b/0xd0
[   59.046971]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x6e/0xd8
[   59.046973] RIP: 0033:0x770a72f2799d
[   59.046995] Code: 28 89 54 24 1c 48 89 74 24 10 89 7c 24 08 e8 6a 90 f6 ff 8b 54 24 1c 48 8b 74 24 10 41 89 c0 8b 7c 24 08 b8 2e 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 00 f0 ff ff 77 33 44 89 c7 48 89 44 24 08 e8 ae 90 f6 ff 48
[   59.046996] RSP: 002b:00007ffea43fcf80 EFLAGS: 00000293 ORIG_RAX: 000000000000002e
[   59.046998] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 00007ffea43fd050 RCX: 0000770a72f2799d
[   59.046999] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 00007ffea43fcfc0 RDI: 000000000000000b
[   59.047000] RBP: 00005b87c5fb5c80 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000011
[   59.047001] R10: 00005b87c6079e20 R11: 0000000000000293 R12: 00005b87c5fb5c80
[   59.047002] R13: 00005b87c5f4de80 R14: 00007ffea43fd290 R15: 00007ffea43fd294
[   59.047005]  </TASK>
[   59.047006] ---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---
```

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl NetworkManager service`. Also do: `service NetworkManager status` and `service --status-all`.

Comment: Updated my BIOS and that seems to have kept it up for the longest time yet. No failure so far

Comment: And not 2 minutes after posting that it died again...

Comment: @waltinator I've added that information and 3 pastebins that provide a lot more information. When the wifi fails and I restart the network manager, I still can't access wifi. I've only been able to fix with restarts

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it was power control. I did two things and so far have not had any issues since doing them.

`sudo iwconfig wlp9s0 power off`

`sudo vim /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf` and set
`wifi.powersave=0`

## Edit

set `wifi.powersave = 2`

According to [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/voidlinux/comments/rapmhh/comment/hnkn7pr/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button) wpa_supplicant and NetworkManager can interfere with each other. I [disabled wpa_supplicant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66000039/5217293) and have not yet had any issues. Time will tell if I'm lying, but it's been a few hours and no issues have presented.

aaaand **not even 5 minutes** after posting that the wifi died again

Comment: wifi.powersave=2 is the preferred setting

Comment: This was a lie. Almost immediately after posting this it stopped working